# How to make GCC warnings go to stdout instead of stderr?

Tags: gcc, azure-devops, continuous-integration, stderr

In our continuous integration system, we have a C++ project being built with GCC.
The pipeline treats output to stderr as meaning the build has failed.
It looks like GCC outputs all warnings and errors to stderr - so any warnings output cause the build to 'fail'.

Is there a way to make GCC only output actual errors to stderr and not warnings as well?

Comment: `The pipeline treats output to stderr as meaning the build has failed` Why? That sounds strange. What would happen if the compilation would fail, but there would be no output to stderr?

Comment: Well I guess the pipeline would think that the compile stage had succeeded - but one of the later stages which copy the built files would fail when it can't find the build output.

Comment: Can you show your pipeline?

Comment: Did the error come from the build task, or the copy file task. If it is the copy file task in the later stages which failed, then you should check the configuration of the copy file task. Could you share a piece of the error log?

Comment: There aren't any issues with the pipeline or GCC build itself. The issue is just when we turn on the option in Azure Devops "failOnStderr” to catch GCC errors from our bash script which compiles the c++ source with GCC. The problem arising from this is that GCC outputs warnings to stderr - so that causes the build task to fail - we only want the task to fail when GCC outputs an actual error - not a warning.

Comment: Why not just switch off `failOnStderr`? If you're worried about not catching errors, gcc should still return a non-zero exit code in the case of a failed compile, which will also cause Azure DevOps to fail that step. (Unless you're calling gcc from a script that does something else after, in which case you'd need to tweak it to pass the exit code back through to the pipeline.)

Comment: Thanks @SorenBjornstad, that is basically what I've done now - improved the script to check all the return values from gcc calls and pass it back

Answer (score 0):

Add `2>&1` after your command to make it send it's stderr output to stdout.